# How to use class fields with System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer?

Tags: c#, json.net, .net-core-3.0, system.text.json

I recently upgraded a solution to be all .NET Core 3 and I have a class that requires the class variables to be fields. This is a problem since the new `System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer` doesn't support serializing nor deserializing fields but only handles properties instead.

Is there any way to ensure that the two final classes in the example below have the same exact values?

```
using System.Text.Json;

public class Car
{
    public int Year { get; set; } // does serialize correctly
    public string Model; // doesn't serialize correctly
}

static void Problem() {
    Car car = new Car()
    {
        Model = "Fit",
        Year = 2008,
    };
    string json = JsonSerializer.Serialize(car); // {"Year":2008}
    Car carDeserialized = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Car>(json);

    Console.WriteLine(carDeserialized.Model); // null!
}
```

Answer (score 56, accepted):

In **.NET Core 3.x**, System.Text.Json does not serialize fields.  From the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-how-to?pivots=dotnet-core-3-1#include-fields):

> Fields are not supported in System.Text.Json in .NET Core 3.1. Custom converters can provide this functionality.

In **.NET 5** and later, public fields can be serialized by setting [`JsonSerializerOptions.IncludeFields`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.jsonserializeroptions.includefields?view=net-5.0) to `true` or by marking the field to serialize with [`[JsonInclude]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.serialization.jsonincludeattribute?view=net-5.0):

```cs
using System.Text.Json;

static void Main()
{
    var car = new Car { Model = "Fit", Year = 2008 };

    // Enable support
    var options = new JsonSerializerOptions { IncludeFields = true };

    // Pass "options"
    var json = JsonSerializer.Serialize(car, options);

    // Pass "options"
    var carDeserialized = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Car>(json, options);

    Console.WriteLine(carDeserialized.Model); // Writes "Fit"
}

public class Car
{
    public int Year { get; set; }
    public string Model;
}
```

For details see:

- [How to serialize and deserialize (marshal and unmarshal) JSON in .NET: Include fields](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-how-to?pivots=dotnet-5-0#include-fields).
- Issues [#34558](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/34558) and [#876](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/876).

Comment: Also documented in [How to serialize and deserialize JSON in .NET: Serialization behavior](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-how-to#serialization-behavior): *By default, all public properties are serialized. You can specify properties to exclude... Currently, fields are excluded.*

Comment: I edited the answer now that it's possible (in pre-release version).

Comment: You can use Sytem.Text.Json >=5.0.2 package in .net core 3.1

Answer (score 5):

If you want this for all MvcControllers in API project you can do similar to this in setup:

```
builder.Services.AddControllers().AddJsonOptions(options =>
{
    options.JsonSerializerOptions.IncludeFields = true;
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Please try this library I wrote as an extension to System.Text.Json to offer missing features: https://github.com/dahomey-technologies/Dahomey.Json.

You will find support for fields.

```
using System.Text.Json;
using Dahomey.Json

public class Car
{
    public int Year { get; set; } // does serialize correctly
    public string Model; // will serialize correctly
}

static void Problem() {
    JsonSerializerOptions options = new JsonSerializerOptions();
    options.SetupExtensions(); // extension method to setup Dahomey.Json extensions

    Car car = new Car()
    {
        Model = "Fit",
        Year = 2008,
    };
    string json = JsonSerializer.Serialize(car, options); // {"Year":2008,"Model":"Fit"}
    Car carDeserialized = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Car>(json);

    Console.WriteLine(carDeserialized.Model); // Fit
}
```