# Web API returns empty json array

Tags: c#, web-services, asp.net-web-api

I've traced through the my method (below) at run time. Below the code I've included a screenshot of the Debug examination of the Portfolios list just before the return statement. I've expanded a couple of the list entries. As you can see, each Portfolio object contains bona fide data - a numeric Id and a string name.

Yet, here's what comes back to the Chrome browser, or postman, no difference.

[{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{}]

What's happening to all the data? Thanks for your help!

```
    // GET: api/Portfolio
    [HttpGet]
    public List<Portfolio> Get()
    {
        List<Portfolio> Portfolios = new List<Portfolio>();

        using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(conn))
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = cn.CreateCommand();
            cmd.CommandText = sqlSelectPortfolios;
            cn.Open();
            SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            Portfolio pf;

            while (rdr.Read())
            {
                pf = new Portfolio
                {
                    id = (int)rdr["PortfolioId"],
                    name = (string)rdr["PortfolioName"]
                };

                Portfolios.Add(pf);
            }
        }

        return Portfolios;
    }
```

Debug:

[image: Debug Screenshot]

Comment: If id and name are fields and you're using System.Text.Json.JsonSerialiser than it won't serialise them as of Nov 2019.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use class fields with System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58139759/how-to-use-class-fields-with-system-text-json-jsonserializer)

Comment: What is your `Portfolio` class code?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `id` and `name` need to be public and properties. As of 3.0 `System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer` does not serialize fields.

```
public class Portfolio 
{
public int id {get; set;}
public string name {get; set;}
}
```

Comment: Thank you!! I had them as public but not defined as properties. As soon as I redefined these as properties I got the expected results.

Comment: The issue is logged as [JsonSerializer should support field as well as properties #36505](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/36505)