# Why does JsonSerializer give empty?

Tags: c#, json, .net-core, system.text.json

Given this class, I am trying to serialize but it isn't working.

```
using System.Text.Json;
public class Service
{
    public Service() { }
    public string service;
    public string description;
}

        Service c = new Service();
        c.description = "desc";
        c.service = "serv";
        string x = JsonSerializer.Serialize<Service>(c);
```

Debugging I see x == "{}".  What am I missing?

C# .net core 3.1

Comment: Those are fields, not properties. Change them to properties.

Comment: There's a few things wrong here. First, your class `Service` is not well formed.  You need getters and setters. But second, this line: `string x = JsonSerializer.Serialize<Service>(c);` is not making sense to me.  You don't need a type when serializing. In other words, you don't need `<Service>`

Comment: @CaseyCrookston Serialize can take a generic.  You're making an assumption that this is JSON.Net or the .Net serializer.  Kentico, for instance, has a [serialize method that does take a generic type parameter](https://devnet.kentico.com/docs/8_2/api/html/M_CMS_DataCom_JsonSerializer_Serialize__1.htm).  The `System.Text.Json` serializer has generic overloads, but they take additional parameters not seen here.  That said, you're right, its not necessary to specify the type.

Comment: @Amy, ok, good to know! I looked at the def for `JsonSerializer.Serialize` before making this comment, and didn't see an option for using a type.

Comment: @CaseyCrookston perhaps the template argument is optional, but MS provided that version and for symmetry with the Deserialize function, why not ?

Comment: @CaseyCrookston You can find them [here on MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.jsonserializer.serialize?view=netcore-3.1).  The 3rd and 4th overloads are generic.  But like I said, they take more than one parameter.

Comment: Fields are not supported by `System.Text.Json`, see [How to use class fields with System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58139759/3744182).  Use properties instead.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are missing setter and getter

```
public class Service
{
    public Service() { }
    public string service {get; set;}
    public string description {get; set;}
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
public class Service
{
    public Service() { }
    public string SomethingElse { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

A couple of things about your class.

1) You will need getters and setters on your properties (as others have pointed out)

2) C# best practice is to capitalize the first letter of class properties.

3) You really don't want to use a property with the same name as the class name.

```
Service c = new Service
{
    Description = "desc",
    SomethingElse = "serv"
};
string x = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(c);
```

This code gives you this for `x`:

```
{"SomethingElse":"serv","Description":"desc"}
```

Note that when you create a new instance of a class and then immediately fill it up and assign values to the properties, it's best to use the [Object Initializer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/object-and-collection-initializers) approach.

So instead of this:

```
Service c = new Service();
c.description = "desc";
c.service = "serv";
```

It's best to do this:

```
Service c = new Service
{
    Description = "desc",
    SomethingElse = "serv"
};
```

Answer (score 0):

this is a correct example:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System;
using Microsoft;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Service c = new Service();
        c.description = "desc";
        c.service = "serv";
        string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(c, Formatting.Indented);
        Console.WriteLine(json);

    }

    public class Service
    {
        public Service() { }
        public string service;
        public string description;
    }


}
```

Comment: Newtonsoft.Json.  I guess I needed to specify I have System.Text.Json.  Didn't realize other libraries existed besides the default.

Comment: @AlanBaljeu Several exists.  `System.Text.Json` is actually the youngest of the bunch.

Comment: young = new and better?

Comment: I still prefer Newtonsoft.Json. All CoolLife did here is switch from `JsonSerializer.Serialize` to `JsonConvert.SerializeObject`. I tested his code. It works.

Comment: @AlanBaljeu Newer anyway.  The *original* .Net serializer was pretty slow and didn't have a lot of features, so Newtonsoft was made, which was *the* JSON serialization library for a long time.  Microsoft learned from Newtonsoft and made the new API.  I don't know if it's as feature-rich.  Newtonsoft is a very powerful library, and hard to beat, in my opinion.

Comment: @AlanBaljeu Kentico and Unity have their own JSON serialization utilities, but they aren't general purpose like the others are, nor are they are robust.