# System.Text.Json JsonSerializer.Deserialize ignortes PropertyNamingPolicy

Tags: c#, .net-core, json.net, c#-8.0, system.text.json

I'm interfacing with an API which uses snake_case as convention names. I would like to map them to fields which are named with CamelCase. Previously, I've used Newtonsoft.Json's `NamingStrategy`. A System.Text.Json equivalent seems to be `PropertyNamingPolicy`.

I've created a global JsonSerializerOptions object and set the `PropertyNamingPolicy` as follows:

```
public static readonly `JsonSerializerOptions` JsonSettings = new JsonSerializerOptions()
{
    Converters =
    {
        new GatewayMessageJsonConverter(),
        new HeartbeatMessageJsonConverter(),
        new OpcodeJsonConverter(),
        new InstantJsonConverter()
    },
    IgnoreNullValues = true,
    PropertyNamingPolicy = new JsonSnakeCaseNamingPolicy(),
    DictionaryKeyPolicy = new JsonSnakeCaseNamingPolicy()
};
```

Which I use while deserializing by passing it as an argument:

```
JsonSerializer.Deserialize<GatewayRestResponse>(responseString.Result, JsonSettings)
```

This however does not work. Debugging seems to indicate that the `ConvertName` function in the `JsonSnakeCaseNamingPolicy` never even gets called.

Is my configuration wrong, or does System.Text.Json not support this?

Comment: *I would like to map them to fields...*  **`System.Text.Json` does not support fields.**  If you are really using fields not properties, that's your problem.  See [How to use class fields with System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58139759/3744182).  Otherwise, please [edit] your question and include a [mcve] so we can help you.

Comment: It seems like that was the issue. Thank you, I did not know there was a difference.

Comment: It's reasonable to be surprised, other serializers besides `System.Text.Json` can serialize public fields.  Not sure why microsoft made that choice.