# Asp.Net Core Web Api, Json Object not return child objects in Complex object

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I have Asp.Net core 3.1 Web Api where a complex object sould be returned by an action like a Json, the problem is that the returned object does not contain the list of child objects:

Below the object:

```
public class DepartementViewModel
{
    public int Dep_ID { get; set; }
    public string Dep_Name { get; set; }

    public List<BasicEmpViewModel> listEmployees = new List<BasicEmpViewModel>();
}
```

And the Action

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<DepartementViewModel>>> GetDepartement()
{
    IRepository IRepos = new DepartementRepository(_context);
    IList<DepartementViewModel> ilIst = await IRepos.GetList();
    return Ok(ilIst);
}
```

The repository GetList function

```
public async Task<IList<DepartementViewModel>> GetList()
{
    IList<DepartementViewModel> listDept = new List<DepartementViewModel>();
    listDept = await(from dept in _context.Departement                        
                          orderby dept.Dep_ID ascending
                              select new DepartementViewModel
                              {
                                  dept.Dep_ID ,
                                  dept.Dep_Name
                              }
                     ).ToListAsync();

    listDept.ForEach(x =>
    {       
        var emObj =_context.Employee;
        foreach (Employee E in emObj)
        {
            E.listEmployees.Add(new BasicEmpViewModel()
                                    {
                                        Emp_ID = E.Emp_ID,
                                        Emp_Name = E.Emp_Name,
                                        Checked = (E.Dep_ID == x.Dep_ID) ? true : false
                                    }
                                );
        }
    }); 

    return listDept;
}
```

The returned Json object does not contain the list of employees "listEmployees", it just displays information relating to the main object :Dep_ID  and Dep_Name.

Is there something missing in my code ?.

Thank you

Comment: Do you use EF? Did you forget `Include` employees at method which retrieve data? 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data/

Comment: Is jsonarray for empoyee list's key is listEmployees?

Comment: I didn't use include but I used Linq requests to populate the object and the object is well populated but it doesn't show the list "listEmployees " in the Json object

Comment: Show `IRepos.GetList` code

Comment: Can you debug and see if "ilist" contains any employess before converting to json?

Comment: I Added the IRepos.GetList function

Answer (score 7):

I have found the solution, I publish the solution for any such problem. indeed it is necessary to put a Getter and Setter for the property listEmployees in the class DepartementViewModel like below

```
public class DepartementViewModel
{
    public int Dep_ID { get; set; }
    public string Dep_Name { get; set; }

    public List<BasicEmpViewModel> listEmployees {get; set; };
}
```

Cordially

Comment: This should be the Accepted answer here. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I suppose perhaps you are using `System.Text.Json` library to serialize and deserialize data in the .net core application, right? If that is the case, perhaps the issue is related this library. As far as I know, when we using the `System.Text.Json` library to serialize complex object, it will only return the outer object (without the inner entities).

To solve this issue, you could try to use the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson` library to serialize data. Refer the following steps:

1. Install `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson` package via Nuget.
2. Register the `NewtonsoftJson` in the Startup.ConfigureServices method:

   ```
        services.AddControllersWithViews().AddNewtonsoftJson();
   ```

Here are some related articles about the `System.Text.Json` and `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson`, you could refer them:

[How to serialize and deserialize (marshal and unmarshal) JSON in .NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-how-to)

[How to migrate from Newtonsoft.Json to System.Text.Json](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-migrate-from-newtonsoft-how-to)

Comment: I changed the method with the use System.Text.Json but the problem still persists, the list listEmployees is not returned in the Json object
below the code:

Comment: var options = new JsonSerializerOptions
{
   PropertyNamingPolicy = JsonNamingPolicy.CamelCase,
   WriteIndented = true
};
   
IList<DepartementViewModel> ilIst = await IRepos.GetList();
var modelJson = JsonSerializer.Serialize(ilIst, options);
return Ok(modelJson);

Comment: Yes, I know that. I have created a sample based on your code and reproduced the problem. If I use the `System.Text.Json`, it will show this issue. After changing the to use the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson` library, everything works well. So, I suggest you try to use the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson` library, instead of 'System.Text.Json'.

Comment: I get the solution, i should put the Getter and setter for listEmployees  property

Answer (score 3):

Took some digging to find, but your issue is that `listEmployees` is a *field*. Currently, `System.Text.Json` only supports the [serialization of *properties*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-migrate-from-newtonsoft-how-to#public-and-non-public-fields). You'll need to either change `listEmployees` to a property or use `Newtonsoft.Json`.

[Related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58139759/how-to-use-class-fields-with-system-text-json-jsonserializer)