# System.Text.Json deserialize uint

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc, json-deserialization, system.text.json

So it seems like the new Json library doesn't deserialize ( or even serialize for that matter) the `UInt32` types. In an MVC application the following is sent in the payload of a POST:

```
{
   "Overrides":{
      
   },
   "Directions":{
      "data1" : "data2"
   },   
   "ModeId": "1782354543",
   "TestNumber" : 10
}
```

And the class it should be serialized to is like this:

```
public class Payload
    {
        public uint ModeId;
        public Dictionary<string, string> Directions{ get; set; } = new();
        public Dictionary<string, string> Overrides { get; set; } = new();
        public int TestNumber { get; set; }
    }
```

But when the request is received, `ModeId` is 0. I tried adding a custom converter based on the unit tests I found [here](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/81bf79fd9aa75305e55abe2f7e9ef3f60624a3a1/src/libraries/System.Text.Json/tests/Serialization/CustomConverterTests.Int32.cs)
Like so:

```
public class UIntConverter : JsonConverter<uint>
    {
        public override uint Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options)
        {
            if (reader.TokenType == JsonTokenType.String)
            {
                string stringValue = reader.GetString();
                if (uint.TryParse(stringValue, out uint x))
                {
                    return x;
                }
            }
            if (reader.TokenType == JsonTokenType.Number)
            {
                return reader.GetUInt32();
            }

            throw new JsonException();
        }

        public override void Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, uint value, JsonSerializerOptions options)
        {
            writer.WriteNumberValue(value);
        }
    }
```

And registering it like this:

```
services.AddControllers()
                .AddJsonOptions(options =>
                {
                    options.JsonSerializerOptions.WriteIndented = false;
                    options.JsonSerializerOptions.IgnoreNullValues = true;
                    options.JsonSerializerOptions.PropertyNamingPolicy = null;
                    options.JsonSerializerOptions.Encoder = JavaScriptEncoder.UnsafeRelaxedJsonEscaping;
                    options.JsonSerializerOptions.Converters.Add(new JsonStringEnumConverter());
                    options.JsonSerializerOptions.Converters.Insert(options.JsonSerializerOptions.Converters.Count,new UIntConverter());

                });
```

I even failed to serialize my class into string using the same converter. It just ignores the uid property.

```
var payload = new Payload()
{
   Directions = new Directions
   {
     {"data1", "data2" }
   },
   ModeId = 1782354543,
   TestNumber = 10
}
//then try to serialize
var defaultJsonSerializerSettings = new JsonSerializerOptions()
        {
            IgnoreNullValues = true,
            WriteIndented = false,
            PropertyNamingPolicy = null,
            Encoder = JavaScriptEncoder.UnsafeRelaxedJsonEscaping,
            Converters = { new UIntConverter()}            
        };
Serializer.Serialize(payload, typeof(Payload), defaultJsonSerializerSettings);
```

It serializes everything, except the uint property which is ignored altogether.

What do you suggest/advise for the serialization/deserialization of a uint property?

[UPDATE] : The issue was the fact that I was trying to serialize/deserialize a field as opposed to a property with public accessors as is pointed out in the answers. It just so happened that field was of type `uint`.

Comment: Possibly the cause: [Fields are not supported in System.Text.Json in .NET Core 3.1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-how-to?pivots=dotnet-core-3-1#include-fields)

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/q/58139759/5803406

Comment: I.e., you're missing `{get; set;}` in `public uint ModeId;` (is that intentional?), then your converter can work. --  `= new()` is not needed.

Comment: uint works fine

Comment: @Keith Nicholas  Yep, setting `NumberHandling = JsonNumberHandling.AllowReadingFromString` among the options. Or include Fields, setting `IncludeFields = true`. So many possibilities...

Comment: Less likely, but also possible: your converter is inserted at the end of the Converters list; is there a compatible converter in the list before yours?

Comment: @devNull yes, that was exactly the issue. Right in my face! Thanks for the hint.

Comment: @Jimi It was not intentional. It was missing the accessors. And that was the issue. Thanks for the hint about including fields. I was looking for an option that allows parsing numbers, I tried different JsonNumberHandling options, but who'd have thought that Fields are the issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're on .NET 5, or if - as @Jimi pointed out - install `<PackageReference Include="System.Text.Json" Version="5.0.2" />`, you can then use `IncludeFields` and `AllowReadingFromString` options:

```
var serializeOptions = new JsonSerializerOptions
{
    IncludeFields = true,
    NumberHandling = JsonNumberHandling.AllowReadingFromString
};

var p = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Payload>(json, serializeOptions);
```

Before .NET5 you'll need to change ModeId to be a property.

---

BTW. You could deal with string/int with no converter:

```
public string ModeId {get; set}
public uint ModeIdParsed => uint.Parse(ModeId);
```

If you need to keep `ModeId` name then you could

```
public class Payload
{
   [JsonPropertyName("ModeId")]
   public string modeId {get;set;}

   [JsonIgnore]
   public uint ModeId => uint.Parse(modeId);
}
```

Unfortunately in 3.1 you'll need to keep the string variant public (deserializing privates is available from v5).

Comment: That's of course correct, but it's not the .Net version, it's the `System.Text.Json` version that matters. You can add v.5.0.2 to .Net Framework, too, just getting the [NuGet Package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Text.Json).

Comment: Thank you both for the clues. The issue as Jimi had pointed out was the field. And turns out it doesn't need a converter as you pointed. I'm using .net5 and System.Text.Json 5.0.2