# Dictionary<string,long> is not being serialized

Tags: json, serialization, system.text.json

I am trying to serialize a simple class:

```
public class Offer_RPC
{
    /// <summary>
    /// this dictionary contains your requested additions ans substractions, in mojos.<br/>
    /// if you wan to offer an nft for example, use the launcher id such as <br/>
    /// "1": 1000000000000 (offer for 1 xch) <br/>
    /// "cc4138f8debe4fbedf26ccae0f965be19c67a49d525f1416c0749c3c865dxxx", -1 <br/>
    /// </summary>
    public Dictionary<string, long> offer = new Dictionary<string, long>();
    public override string ToString()
    {
        JsonSerializerOptions options = new JsonSerializerOptions();
        options.WriteIndented = false;
        options.DefaultIgnoreCondition = System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonIgnoreCondition.WhenWritingNull;
        string jsonString = JsonSerializer.Serialize(this, options: options);
        return jsonString;
    }
}
```

when calling .ToString(), the resulting json is `{}`

This is my test method:

```
[Fact]
public void TestOffer()
{
    Offer_RPC test = new Offer_RPC();
    test.offer.Add("1", 1);
    test.offer.Add("2", -1);
    string json = test.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Either convert your `offer` field to a property or see [How to use class fields with System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58139759/3744182).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`offer` is a field and by default fields are not serialized by the System.Text.Json serialiser.

You can:

1. Make `offer` a property:
   `public Dictionary<string, long> Offer { get; } = new ...`
2. Include fields:

   ```
   var options = new JsonSerializerOptions
   {
        IncludeFields = true,
   };
   var json = JsonSerializer.Serialize(o, options);
   ```

Comment: is this part `Offer { get; } = new ...` also possible with {get;set;}? 
{set;} might be required to deserialize from json

Comment: Yes it could be `{ get;  set; }`.

Comment: BTW. If you change `offers` to `Offers` you may want to use `[JsonPropertyName("offer")]` because `Sytem.Text.Json` is case-sensitive.

Answer (score 1):

just fix the class offer property by adding a getter

```
public Dictionary<string, long> offer { get; } = new Dictionary<string, long>();
```

Answer (score 0):

The Issue is that offer is not a public Property. The class should look like this:

```
public class Offer_RPC
{
    public Offer_RPC()
    {
        offer = new Dictionary<string, long>();
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// this dictionary contains your requested additions ans substractions, in mojos.<br/>
    /// if you wan to offer an nft for example, use the launcher id such as <br/>
    /// "1": 1000000000000 (offer for 1 xch) <br/>
    /// "cc4138f8debe4fbedf26ccae0f965be19c67a49d525f1416c0749c3c865dxxx", -1 <br/>
    /// </summary>
    public Dictionary<string, long> offer { get; set; }
    public override string ToString()
    {
        JsonSerializerOptions options = new JsonSerializerOptions();
        options.WriteIndented = false;
        options.DefaultIgnoreCondition = System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonIgnoreCondition.WhenWritingNull;
        string jsonString = JsonSerializer.Serialize(this, options: options);
        return jsonString;
    }
}
```